# How to avoid the error stty: 'standard input': inappropriate ioctl for device?

Tags: bash

I want to pass two inputs (passwords) to the command grub2-setpassword.

```
echo -e "linuxpassword\nlinuxpassword" | grub2-setpassword
```

However, I'm getting this error on CentOS 7:

```
stty: 'standard input': inappropriate ioctl for device
```

How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to go against the nature of grub's password tool, so you have to jump through hoops to get there : drive the terminal directly via expect or perl or python (etc.) or find a new tool.

[Scriptable grub2-mkpasswd my passwd on github](https://github.com/ryran/burg2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2) may help.